# Datatables Search for data and addClass upon mtach

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatable

I have an array of integers that I need to match to rows of my datatable, specifically the data in column 0. I then need to  set the class for that specific row to "selected" prior to the datatable coming into view for the user.

At present, this is what I have put together as the most efficient way to achieve what I strive for:

```
for aLocation in previouslySelectedLocations
  root.table.column(0).search(aLocation).addClass("selected")
```

It is written in jQuery, and the previouslySelectedLocations object is an array with ids of those locations of interest. I then loop through attempting to match with the hidden id column(0) with root.table.column(0).search(aLocation), and then addClass("selected") to the matched rows.

At present the code doesn't do what is intended but runs the error that it is not a function and present loading:

[image]

Comment: use the column render callback to do this

Comment: What is the column render callback? Can you provide an example?

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render Focus on the function approaches